# UIView notification when modal UIImagePickerController is dismissed?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, ios, modal-dialog

Is there a way to call code when a modal view is finished dismissing?

EDIT:

I'm sorry, I didn't clarify earlier. I'm trying to dismiss a UIImagePickerController and then show a MFMailComposeViewController and attach the image data to the email. When I try to call

`[self presentModalViewController: mailController]`

right after

`[self dismissModalViewController];`

I get errors and such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use a delegate pattern for the modal view to inform whoever presented it when it's finished.

MyModalViewController.h:

```
@protocol MyModalViewControllerDelegate;

@interface MyModalViewController : UIViewController
{
    id<MyModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end


@protocol MyModalViewControllerDelegate
- (void)myModalViewControllerFinished:(MyModalViewController*)myModalViewController;
@end
```

MyModalViewController.m:

```
@synthesize delegate;

// Call this method when the modal view is finished
- (void)dismissSelf
{
    [delegate myModalViewControllerFinished:self];
}
```

ParentViewController.h:

```
#import "MyModalViewController.h"

@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController <MyModalViewControllerDelegate>
{
}
```

ParentViewController.m:

```
- (void)presentMyModalViewController
{
    MyModalViewController* myModalViewController = [[MyModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyModalView" bundle:nil];
    myModalViewController.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:myModalViewController animated:YES];
    [myModalViewController release];
}

- (void)myModalViewControllerFinished:(MyModalViewController*)myModalViewController
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**EDIT:**

I haven't used `UIImagePickerController`, but looking at the docs, it looks like you already have most of the code done for you, as there is an existing [`UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007069) class that has three different "dismissal" delegate callbacks (although one is deprecated). So you should make your `ParentViewController` class (whatever that is) implement the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` pattern and then implement those methods. While each method will do something different (since you have to handle when the user actually selects an image, or if they cancel), they each will do the same thing at the end: call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` to dismiss the picker.

Comment: Can I use the delegate pattern with custom delegates on a UIImagePickerController?

Answer (score 0):

You have to dismiss the modalViewController somehow right? Either a UIButton, or by code:

```
- (void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

In the IBAction (e.g. delegate) for the UIButton or in the method above, call whatever code you want.

Comment: You're saying to override `- (void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated`? I don't think that would work, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a specific notification yet can subscribe to, to know when dismiss animation is done,...BUT. You can implement `viewDidAppear:` in the view controller that presented the modal view. This is what I do, when I use the (to UIImagePickerController quite similar) ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.

In the callback from people picker, I remember the person tapped in the picker on an instance variable, like this:

```
- (void)callbackFromModalView:(id)dataFromModalView {
    // remember dataFromModalView as I need it when dismissed
    self.dataFromModalView = dataFromModalView;

    // now initiate dismissal
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

then, in your view controller, implement this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (self.dataFromModalView) {
        //...present now view here

        // don't forget to reset this one
        self.dataFromModalView = nil;
    }
}
```

in effect, you are using the combination of `viewWillAppear:` and the `dataFromModalView` property as the "notification about modal view dismissed".